# How do I implement a local planner that doesn't rotate in place?

Tags: ros, navigation, base-local-planner, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to using the navigation stack, and I have a robot with Ackermann steering. When I simulate the robot, any 2D Nav Goal set behind it will cause the robot to freeze up, publishing angular cmd_vel values which it cannot realize. I'm looking to tweak the local planner so that I can match the capabilities of my robot. The docs say that dwa_local_planner is more modular, so I plan to use it (unless there is a reason I should use the regular base_local_planner). I know this is probably really simple, but I can't find anything in the documents that goes through this process.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119161/how-do-i-implement-a-local-planner-that-doesn%27t-rotate-in-place?/) by [nc61](https://answers.ros.org/users/6731/nc61/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Just to be sure we're on the same page first: `move_base` is what actually sends `cmd_vel` commands to the robot, based on the plan from your local planner, so the parameters I'll refer to would be set for that node.

From my experience, the robot will only spin in place during clearing behavior, not during navigation (ie if my robot is pointed along some positive x axis and I set the goal somewhere on the negative x axis, it will follow an arc to get there, not rotate in place). It's possible I've just never noticed this, but looking back at videos of it running there's never any in-place rotation.

With that in mind, does it stop giving the impossible commands if you disable rotation in place for clearing behavior by setting `~clearing_rotation_allowed` to false? There's more details on this at [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Parameters) under section "1.1.6 Parameters".

Let me know how that works for you.

-Tim

---

Originally posted by [Tim Sweet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5998/tim-sweet/) with karma: 267 on 2014-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0